# How to sample two values from a random variable X with the lesser to be a random variable Y?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, sampling

The variable X has pdf $$f(x) = \frac18(6 - x)$$ for $$2 ≤ x ≤ 6$$

A sample of two values of X is taken. Denoting the lesser of the two values by Y, use the
cdf of X to write down the cdf of Y. Hence obtain the pdf and mean of Y .
Show that its median is approximately 2.64. (The median is the point m
for which P(Y ≤ m) = 0.5.)

This is an exercise of Probability theory. It has been bothering me for a long time. Really thank you for helping me.

I am stuck in the first step:using the cdf of X to write down the cdf of Y.

I tried the Inverse function of cumulative distribution function, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: At which point are you stuck?  E.g. the first step would be to recognize that $P(Y \le a) = P(X_1 \le a \cap X_2 \le a) = P(X_1 \le a) \cdot P(X_2 \le a) = cdf_X(a)^2$...

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin  Thanks, I am trying to learn it.

Comment: @gong.y - Obviously you are new here, so FYI the common etiquette is to not just list the problem but also tell people what you have tried, where you are stuck.  This problem is a good example -- it has multiple steps and I had to guess where you are stuck.  :)

Comment: @antkam Yes, you are totally right. I get it now.

Comment: @antkam  I use the square of the cdf of X as the cdf of Y for [2, 6]. But the total  probability is not 1. I don't know why...

Comment: I edited the post to settle an ambiguity in the expression.  I think the PDF must be $\frac18(6-x)$ because its integral over $[2, 6]$ is $1$, whereas the integral of $\frac{1}{8(6-x)}$ does not converge over that interval.  Please check that this is what is intended.

Comment: @BrianTung  Yes. I was editting just now noticing you were editting too.

Comment: @BrianTung Would you please show me how to write  the cdf of Y?

Comment: Check my answer.  Graham Kemp's answer shows you how to move on from there.

Comment: @antkam: The second term should be a disjunction, not a conjunction, so a slightly different manipulation is called for.

Comment: @BrianTung - Oh man!  You are right!  The $\min$ is less than $a$ iff either one is less than $a$.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to follow the hint of antkam, and use the CDF of $Y$, it is necessary first to find the CDF of $X$.  What we have now is the PDF of $X$.  We must first integrate that with respect to $x$:

$$
F_X(x) = \int \frac18 (6-x) \, dx = \frac18 \left(6x-\frac12x^2\right) + C
       = \frac34 x - \frac{1}{16}x^2 + C, \qquad 2 \leq x \leq 6
$$

We need $F_X(2) = 0$, which yields $C = -\frac54$ and then

$$
F_X(x) = \frac34 x - \frac{1}{16}x^2 - \frac54
$$

As a check, we observe that $F_X(6) = \frac92 - \frac94 - \frac54 = 1$, as it should.  You should now be able to identify the proper CDF for $Y$, and to determine the median for $Y$.  Be aware that

$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = 1-P(Y > y) = 1-[P(X > y)]^2 = 1-[1-F_X(x)]^2
$$

so the hint of antkam is slightly off.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $X_1,X_2$ be the two samples, so $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2\}$. $$\mathsf P(Y\leqslant y)~{=1-\mathsf P(y<Y)\\[2ex]=~1-\mathsf P(y<\min\{X_1,X_2\})\\[2ex]=1-\mathsf P(y<X_1)~\mathsf P(y<X_2)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! sorry I can only accept one answer.